# Wildfly CLI remove using wildcard

Tags: command-line-interface, jboss7.x, wildfly, wildfly-8

In Wildfly (version 8.2.1) CLI, is there a way to remove using wildcard?
For example, if I want to remove all broadcast groups, and I don't want to specify the name:

```
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/broadcast-group=*/:remove
```

I'm getting an error

```
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "JBAS014646: Cannot remove *",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you have to remove all resources one at a time. Wild cards can only be used in most read operations. All write and remove operations require explicit paths.